# How can these two be equivalent (wolfram-alpha incorrect) !?

Tags: calculus, integration, wolfram-alpha

So wolfram-alpha reads The integral of $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)$$ but that $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx \;\mathrm{where}\; a=5 \;\mathrm{is}\; \sin^{-1}{(\frac{x}{5})}$$

I have no idea why the integration varies based on a cleanly pluggable value of a.  Could someone be so kinda as to explain what just happened? 
 (I ran $\mathrm{is }\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}})\;\mathrm{equal}\;\mathrm{to}\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$, and the result was [***false***](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e7sl26j3r3s)!)

Comment: Why didn't you check whether $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5^2-x^2}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)$$ which is the relevant question?

Comment: Also, what is b?

Comment: [Facepalm](http://i.imgur.com/L3J6n.jpg) And $b$ was a typo.

Comment: When you're dealing with trigonometric functions, it's very easy to forget the basic underlying structure: their relationships on a right triangle.

Comment: Welcome to trigonometry.

Answer (score 2):

If $$\theta =  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)$$
you have 
$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}.$$
Draw the triangle.  opposite $= x$, adjacent $=\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$, and so
hypotenuse $=a$.  Now compute the trig ratios.
The simplest is $\sin(\theta) = {x\over a}.$
I think you are missing a factor of $1/a$.

Answer (score 1):

These results are of course the same.
To see this, plug in: 
$$x = a\sin \theta$$
And remember that $1 - \sin^2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta$.

The reason wolfram doesn't think so probably has to do with the domain, since the functions are no longer the same if $|a| < |x|$.